# D3 Graph working in chromium, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to access dates and some values in `d3` js. Shared my fiddle, can any one help me out in correcting my code and can any one tell me the mistake as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>trial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
     <body>
     <svg id="visualisation" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js' ></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.12/d3.min.js"></script>

     <script src="js/index.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c6jf5yg0/6/

Observation: The attribute id is not computing properly in the broswers.
 thanks in advance

Comment: Chromium / chrome browser ?

Comment: hey, the issue seems to be with the date format that you're using. Chromium is able to parse the date, but other browsers aren't.

Comment: yea the issue  is with the extent method (found out using debugger ) how to replace it with the min and max methods can u please help me

Comment: chromium @Venkatraman

Comment: @user3398900, posted two answers. one is with detailed root cause and another one is ECMA Standard and solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the "T" in between date and time and that is `ECMA Specification`
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2

#### Working Demo:

```js
        InitChart();

        function InitChart() {

        var lineData = [{
                    "x": "2016-01-08T03:01:19.418110",
                    "y": 0.8076999999999999
                }, {
                    "x": "2016-01-08T05:10:19.838509",
                    "y": 0.692666666666667
                }, {
                    "x": "2016-01-08T09:54:13.022163",
                    "y": 0.5674333333333333
                }];

            var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
                WIDTH = 1000,
                HEIGHT = 500,
                MARGINS = {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 50
                },

                xRange = d3.time.scale()
                .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right])
                .domain(d3.extent(lineData, function(d) {
                    return new Date(d.x);
                })),

                yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function(d) {
                        return d.y;
                    }),
                    d3.max(lineData, function(d) {
                        return d.y;
                    })
                ]),

                xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xRange)
                .tickSize(5)
                .tickSubdivide(true)
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%X')),

                yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yRange)
                .tickSize(5)
                .orient("left")
                .tickSubdivide(true);


            vis.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            vis.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);

            var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) {
                    return xRange(new Date(d.x));
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                    return yRange(d.y);
                })
                .interpolate('linear');

            vis.append("svg:path")
                .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData))
                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("fill", "none");

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>trial</title>
<body>
    <svg id="visualisation" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Path` element attribute value has `NaN` firefox is the first root cause.

```
<path d="MNaN,20LNaN,240.23584905660306LNaN,480" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
```

#### Why it is updating NaN?

In extent function of X Range like below.

```
d3.extent(lineData, function(d) {
 return new Date(d.x);
  // new Date("2016-01-08 03:01:19.418110");
  // Firefox output Date {Invalid Date}
  // Chrome it works.
})
```

#### How to Fix this issue ?

> Update your lineData like below. by adding T in between date and time.

```
var lineData = [{
            "x": "2016-01-08T03:01:19.418110",
            "y": 0.8076999999999999
        }, {
            "x": "2016-01-08T05:10:19.838509",
            "y": 0.692666666666667
        }, {
            "x": "2016-01-08T09:54:13.022163",
            "y": 0.5674333333333333
        }];
```

#### Working Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: yes venkatraman i debugged this it all because of extent function how can we replace extent with min and max functions?
           xRange = d3.time.scale()
           .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right])
           .domain(d3.extent(lineData, function (d) {
            return new Date(d.x);
             }))

Comment: it is still not coming in mozilla

Comment: I have updated the root cause that your dates are not accepted in firefox

Comment: I understood that venkatraman that is the reason i even mentioned that in my comment how to solve this issue?? :(

Comment: thanks venkatraman one more problem is that after adding T it is showing wrong time in google chrome ... :'(

Comment: i tried it in chrome. its working new Date("2016-01-08T03:01:19.418110")

Fri Jan 08 2016 08:31:19 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)